# Set command timeout EF Core MariaDB

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, mariadb

I am currently using `pomelo.entityframeworkcore.mysql` to interface with MariaDB using EF Core. I am using EF Core version 2.2.2 and `pomelo.entityframeworkcore.mysql` version 2.2.0. I have tried setting the command timeout in the connection string by adding it to the end like this:

```
Server=xxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com;Database=xxxx;User=xxxx;Password=xxxx;default command timeout=120;
```

That did not work so I tried the following:

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(opts => opts.UseMySql(Configuration["ConnectionString:DB"],
                    mySqlOptions => {
                        mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(10, 3, 8), ServerType.MariaDb);
                        mySqlOptions.CommandTimeout(120);
                    })
                .UseSecondLevelCache(), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Which did not work either. Does anyone have another way to set the command timeout?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this one? I"m running into the same issue.